# Not able to display attachement variant in rails react

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have a product image modal

```rb
class ProductImage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product

  has_many_attached :images do |attachable|
    attachable.variant :thumb, resize_to_limit: [100, nil]
  end

  
 def attachement_path
    Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_representation_url(
      images.first, only_path: true
    )
  end

 def attachement_thumb_path
    Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_representation_url(
      images.first.variant(:thumb).processed, only_path: true
    )
  end
end
```

It perfectly generates `attachement_path` and display the Image but in case of `attachement_thumb_path`

It throws the following errors

```
  ActiveStorage::Blob Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_blobs" ("key", "filename", "content_type", "metadata", "byte_size", "checksum", "created_at", "service_name") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["key", "uk368qdr9oq73hdg13mdkicpdwb6"], ["filename", "look15.jpg"], ["content_type", "image/jpeg"], ["metadata", "{\"identified\":true}"], ["byte_size", 14510], ["checksum", "f8/qGVxgNbeK3YZ7t/e/HQ=="], ["created_at", "2022-10-26 11:38:41.592281"], ["service_name", "local"]]
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Create (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_attachments" ("name", "record_id", "record_type", "blob_id", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "image"], ["record_id", nil], ["record_type", "ActiveStorage::VariantRecord"], ["blob_id", "495f44bb-1b19-4279-8331-d7c8d86758f8"], ["created_at", "2022-10-26 11:38:41.593878"]]
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:768:in `exec_params': PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "record_id" of relation "active_storage_attachments" violates not-null constraint (ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation)
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (49bcc6c0-4167-42f4-8687-a245847798ad, image, null, ActiveStorage::VariantRecord, 495f44bb-1b19-4279-8331-d7c8d86758f8, 2022-10-26 11:38:41.593878).
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:768:in `exec_params': ERROR:  null value in column "record_id" of relation "active_storage_attachments" violates not-null constraint (PG::NotNullViolation)
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (49bcc6c0-4167-42f4-8687-a245847798ad, image, null, ActiveStorage::VariantRecord, 495f44bb-1b19-4279-8331-d7c8d86758f8, 2022-10-26 11:38:41.593878).
irb(main):003:0>
```

If I remove the `null: false` validation from record column of `active_storage_attachments` table everything works perfectly But since this table is generated by action storage I dont want to modify it.

Comment: The same error occurs when we run `images.first.variant(:thumb).processed` in console
and images.first.variant(:thumb).image is coming as nil.

Comment: Hi Harshaan, I have the same issue. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Not able to find a solution so I ported to the carrier wave.

I believe there is a possibility that this feature is only present in rails 7
ref: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/41446